# How to call a PHP from another server?

Tags: linux, cron, shell

How to call a PHP from another server using shell script? I have a PHP and shell scripts, the 2 files are stored in different server.

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

php "http://example.com/csv_import.php"
```

But when I run this command manually, I got an error: `Could not open input`

How to call a PHP properly using shell script?

Comment: PHP doesn't take a URL as an argument.  However you got that idea, back up to one step before that and try again.

Comment: Scarily, PHP *can* (depending on how its configured) take a URL directly as an argument to various functions which deal with file input, including, but not limited to, the command line.  This particular variant is one of the less scary invocations, no more insecure than `curl ... | sudo sh`.

Comment: When you visit a URL like `http://example.com/csv_import.php`, it (usually) means that you are asking `example.com` to execute `csv_import.php` on the server. Sending an HTTP request for that URL file causes the result of executing that script to be sent back in the HTTP response. In many cases, the response will contain HTML. If you want to execute `csv_import.php` locally, you'll need to download it using something like `scp` or `sftp` and then run it locally. It is possible to configure the remote machine to respond to the HTTP request with the PHP source code, but I doubt it's wise here.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you want to *execute* the PHP script? If it’s on the other server, then you just need to hit the appropriate URL:

```
curl "http://example.com/csv_import.php"
```

Or, if it requires a POST request,

```
curl -XPOST "http://example.com/csv_import.php"
```

This is fairly simple.

---

However, if you want to *download* a PHP script and run it on *this* server, you’re in a slightly trickier situation. First, you have to ensure that the remote server sends the actual *script*, instead of running the script and sending the result, as would be the normal situation (or, perhaps, you have a script which, when processed, outputs another script). Generally, you can do this by disabling PHP parsing in your web server, or by changing the file extension to something non-standard (probably simply `.txt`).

Now you want to download that script and pass run it with the PHP executable on your local machine. First, check that it works, by running the `curl` command above and checking that the output is, in fact, the PHP script itself. If you’ve achieved this, then something simple like

```
curl "http://example.com/csv_import.php.txt" | php
```

should do the trick.

The tricky bit is at the other end.

If you cannot disable PHP parsing at the other end, you may be able to grab the PHP file from there in some other way, such as `scp` or `rsync`, and then execute it locally.

Answer (score 0):

You use any command line HTTP client like `curl` or `wget` to make the HTTP request.

Comment: That depends on where the OP wants the script to be executed: on the client or on the server.

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
```

I.e. The first argument to php if it doesn't look like an option is the name of the PHP file to execute, and -q is CGI only.